# Improve mysql query for searching chemical reaction

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables 1- tbl_reaction like this:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ id ║ condition ║ phenomenon ║  infor  ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ abcd123   ║ abcd123    ║ abcd123 ║
║  2 ║ wer       ║ wer        ║ wer     ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

2- tbl_reaction_item like this:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ reid ║ substance ║  type   ║ num ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════╣
║    1 ║ H2        ║ income  ║   2 ║
║    1 ║ O2        ║ income  ║   1 ║
║    1 ║ H2O       ║ outcome ║   2 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

To display the reaction:

> income + income = outcome
>
> 2H2 + O2 => 2H2O

I use this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type='income' THEN CONCAT(IF(num=1, '', num),substance) END SEPARATOR ' + '), ' => ',
         GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN type='outcome' THEN CONCAT(IF(num=1, '', num),substance) END SEPARATOR ' + '))
         AS reaction
FROM tbl_reaction_item
GROUP BY reid;
```

But now I would like to use this query to search a substance in reaction

Comment: Do you want to search substances by reid?

Comment: you mean you want to search eg: H2 from the output of the query?

Comment: yes,  
i want to search eg: H2 from the output and input of the query